# how to include hex value in string using sprintf

Tags: c, hex, printf

i want to include value of i hex format in c.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   sprintf(s1"DTLK\x%x\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",i);
```

but the above code outputs an error: \x used with no following hex digits

Pls any one suggest me a proper way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the slash on front of the `\x`:

```
sprintf(s1"DTLK\\x%x\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",i);
//              ^------- Here
```

Depending on what output you would like to achieve, you may need to escape the remaining slashes as well.

Currently, the snippet produces a sequence of six characters with the code `0xFF`. If this is what you want, your code fragment is complete. If you would like to see a sequence of `\xFF` literals, i.e. a string that looks like `\x5\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF` when `i == 5`, you need to escape all slashes in the string:

```
sprintf(s1"DTLK\\x%x\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF",i);
//              ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
```

Finally, if you would like the value formatted as a two-digit hex code even when the value is less than sixteen, use `%02x` format code to tell `sprintf` that you want a leading zero.

Comment: I rather think he wants the other way: the `\xFF` should expand to the value `0xFF` while after the `DTLK` he wants a variable value...

Comment: @glglgl It's hard to say for sure, but that's the only reason why I think the OP would ask specifically for a hex value.

Comment: Some people mix up the characters themselves with their representation; that's why I think the opposite. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you don't want to literally have `\x00`..`\x0A`, but the corresponding byte, you need

```
sprintf(s1, "DTLK%c\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",i);
```

while inserting `\x%x` would be at the wrong abstraction level...

If, OTOH, you really want to literally have the hex characters instead of the bytes with the named hey characters as their representation, the other answers might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`\x` expects a hex value like `\xC9`.

If you want to include `\x` in your output, you need to escape `\` with `\\`:

```
sprintf(s1"DTLK\\x%x\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(s1"DTLK\\x%x\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF",i);
//              ^------- Here
```

Depending on what output you would like to achieve, you may need to escape the remaining slashes as well.

Currently, the snippet produces a sequence of six characters with the code `0xFF`. If this is what you want, your code fragment is complete. If you would like to see a sequence of `\xFF` literals, i.e. a string that looks like `\x5\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF` when `i == 5`, you need to escape all slashes in the string:

```
sprintf(s1"DTLK\\x%x\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF",i);

//              ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
```

Finally, if you would like the value formatted as a two-digit hex code even when the value is less than 16, use `%02x` format code to tell `sprintf` that you want a leading zero.